# Android - Generics and inheritance for todolists

Tags: java, android, list, generics, inheritance

I'm making a Todolist app. There are two types of todolist that can be created. The first is classic, just a collection of strings. And the second is a collection of images (and each image also have a string to describe it).

So my classes are :

ELEMENT

```
public class Element {
    private String text;

    public Element(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void editText(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

ELEMENT IMAGE

```
public class ElementImage extends Element {
    private Image image;

    public ElementImage(String text, Image image){
        super(text);
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void editImage(Image image){
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Then I also have the "todo" classes but I don't really how I need to create them to be able to use the methods of "element" but also the methods of "elementImage" in the case of a Todolist of "elementImage"...

Basically the "todo" classes will contains a name and a List of "element" but I don't know what is the best way to make them in order to have the less duplicated code and not to break solid.

- Using abstract classes for the "todo" ?
- Modifying my "element" classes ?
- Using generics ?
- Something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a good way to start, but you may have to do more if you have more requirements

```
public class Todo<T>{ // T can represent Element or ElementImage or anything you want.
    T element;
    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    public Todo(T element){
        this.element = element;
    }

    T getElemet(){
        return element; // If T is ElementImage or just Element you can get it and do what you want

    }
    // Now you would need to add further logic and more stuff.
    public List<T> getTodoList(){ return list;}
}
```

Comment: Yeah that could be a good idea because in the future I may add more type of list, like audio etc... But with this solution how can I know what type of list this is ? Because I'll need that info for the views...

Comment: for example if you do Todo<Element> todo = new Todo(new Element); Then you know that the list is a List<Element>, if i got your question right.